# u-boot bbappend causes file system corruption

Tags: yocto, u-boot, meta-raspberrypi

I need to configure u-boot to boot immediately (disabling the press key to interrupt prompt) for a yocto build.

I've added the following bbappend to do so:

```
# u-boot_%.bbappend

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/u-boot:"

SRC_URI_append_edge = " \
  file://disable-boot-delay.cfg \
"
```

where `disable-boot-delay.cfg` looks like this:

```
CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED=y
CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED_CTRLC=n
CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=-2
```

This successfully disables the boot prompt, but also causes the FAT partition that u-boot is installed on to become corrupt:

```
$ # without above bbappend
$ dosfsck /dev/mapper/loop0p1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/dev/mapper/loop0p1: 49 files, 6510/20431 clusters
```

```
$ # with above bbappend
$ dosfsck /dev/mapper/loop0p1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/OVERLAYS/.
  Bad short file name (.).
1) Drop file
2) Rename file
3) Auto-rename
4) Keep it
? 4
/OVERLAYS/..
  Bad short file name (..).
1) Drop file
2) Rename file
3) Auto-rename
4) Keep it
? 4
/dev/mapper/loop0p1: 49 files, 6510/20431 clusters
```

I'm massively, massively confused as to how this change could be causing file system corruption.

Environment:

- Yocto Warrior (2.7)
- meta-raspberrypi (warrior branch)
- `RPI_USE_U_BOOT = "1"`

Diffing `workdir/build/.config` with and without the above append:

```
229c229
< CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=2
---
> CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=-2
306c306,311
< # CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED is not set
---
> CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED=y
> CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_PROMPT="Autoboot in %d seconds\n"
> # CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_ENCRYPTION is not set
> CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_DELAY_STR=""
> CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_STOP_STR=""
> # CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED_CTRLC is not set
```

Comment: Diff the configuration file that is actually produced with & without your additions to make sure it's being applied correctly.

Comment: @RichardNixon updated the description with the diff - the config is being applied successfully. But why would that lead to FAT errors?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning - if `disable-boot-delay.cfg` is empty (but included with the recipe append), the FAT partition is fine. If I add just `CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=-2`, or just `CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED=y` and `CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED_CTRLC=n`, the FAT partition is bad.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is something to do with the size of the resulting `u-boot.bin` binary, but not understanding why this would cause problems?

Comment: I've seen config additions badly integrated in the past switching off other important CONFIG_... elements.

Comment: Have you tried adding the config changes one by one?

Comment: I've tried `CONFIG_BOOTDELAY` on its own, which is the one I'm really needing. That causes still causes dosfsck to complain. Regardless, how would switching on / off other `CONFIG_` elements cause the fat partition to be bad in that way?

Comment: @HaydenBall Your choice of `CONFIG_BOOTDELAY` is interesting, as it's a negative number. Did you try setting it to zero?

Comment: @seldak I haven't, however `-2` is a documented option for `CONFIG_BOOTDELAY`: https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/23b93e33adde0a8313388eda7c78d1d0786e3c92/common/Kconfig#L363

Comment: My guess is that a combination of the config fragment plus your `bootcmd` (or some other configuration) is causing a `saveenv` or an environment variable to be written to the VFAT partition which you have u-boot on. Without more information, it will be hard to help. On another note the difference between `0` and `-2` for `CONFIG_BOOTDELAY` is that for the latter u-boot will not check for abort. Both do autoboot without delay which is what you're looking for.